# Benchmark phones using Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, performance, battery, benchmarks

I have a few used phones running identical fresh installs of the current [Ubuntu Touch for Devices](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) and want to benchmark their performance and attributes in the field such as: processor, battery (maximum charge, estimated minutes of standby time, etc.), wireless card, cellular radio, (graphics processor??), and other basics in order to compare the phones.

Is there an Ubuntu Touch package and/or app I can use to benchmark a phone's hardware performance?

If not, do you have suggestions for generating my own home-baked benchmark results?